# Slick carousel how to order slides differently in two rows layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I building a website with [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel and currently the slider orders the slides in this way:

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

and I need it to be in this way:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

is that possible?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/moq3ftu1/4/) with 3 slides. Essentially, I need when there are only three slides for them to be in a single row.

Here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
var slickOptions = {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        rows: 2,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        dotsClass: 'slick-dots slick-dots-black',
        adaptiveHeight: true,
    };
$('#slides').slick(slickOptions);
```

Comment: Yes, it does!!!